# Show that $F(t) = (\cos t, \sin t)$ is locally one-to-one but not globally one-to-one.

Tags: linear-algebra, economics, implicit-function-theorem, inverse-function-theorem, linear-independence

I am studying Implicit Function Theorem and Inverse Function Theorem. The problem I want to ask is:

> Show that $F(t) = (\cos t, \sin t)$  is locally one-to-one but not globally one-to-one.

I have two questions about this problem. First, I tried this problem myself, and would like to know whether my answer is correct or not. Second, I have difficulty understanding the rank of the Jacobian matrix of F.

I applied the following theorem in my answer:

> **Theorem** $\space\space\space\space$ Let $F: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ be a $C^1$ function with $F(\mathbf{x^*}) = \mathbf{b^*}$. Let $DF_{\mathbf{x^*}}$ denote the $m \times n$ Jacobian matrix of $F$ at $\mathbf{x^*}$.
> (a) If $DF_{\mathbf{x^*}}$ is onto ($n \geq m = \text{rank} DF_{\mathbf{x^*}}$), then $F$ is locally onto at $\mathbf{x^*}$.
> (b) If $DF_{\mathbb{x^*}}$ is one-to-one ($m \geq n = \text{rank} DF_{\mathbb{x^*}}$), then $F$ is locally one-to-one at $\mathbf{x^*}$.

Here is my attempt:

> Define $F: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ as $F(t) = (\cos t, \sin t)$. We have
> \begin{equation}
> DF = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial t} \\ \frac{\partial F_2}{\partial t} \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} -\sin t \\ \cos t \end{pmatrix}.
> \end{equation}
> Since $2 = m \geq n = 1 = \text{rank} DF$, by the theorem above, $F$ is locally one-to-one.
> However, $F(0) = F(2\pi)$. So $F$ is not globally one-to-one.

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me check whether my answer is correct or not.

In addition, in my answer, I said $\text{rank} DF = 1$. I can see that since $\begin{pmatrix} -\sin t \\ \cos t \end{pmatrix}$ is a $2 \times 1$ matrix, then it has to be of rank $1$. However, since column rank equals row rank I should be able to conclude that $-\sin t$ and $\cos t$ are linearly dependent. But this is obviously absurd. What am I missing?

(Source: *Mathematics for Economists* by Simon and Blume Chapter 15 Exercise 37)

Comment: More to the point, for what value of $t$ does the matrix have rank $0$?

Comment: @TedShifrin Under no circumstance will the matrix have rank $0$, because $DF$ is never going to be a zero matrix.

Comment: Are you trying to show $-\sin t$ and $\cos t$ are linearly dependent over $\mathbb{R}$ for any particular $t$-value or are you trying to show they're linearly dependent over $\mathbb{R}$ as functions?  (the former is shown by $\cos t(-\sin t) + \sin t(\cos t) = 0$, while the latter isn't true)

Comment: @BrianMoehring I think I want to show that $-\sin t$ and $\cos t$ are linearly dependent for any $t$. (I just amended my second question a bit.)

Comment: You can show local one-one without calling on theorems about Jacobians. $\cos t$ is locally one-one except at multiples of $\pi$, and $\sin t$ is locally one-one there.

Comment: @GerryMyerson That does make sense. Thank a lot! But I am still confused about the Jacobian's rank and the linear (in)dependence of its rows.

Comment: @BrianMoehring I think I get your point. Correct me if I am wrong. Since I am showing that $-\sin t$ and $\cos t$ are linearly dependent for any $t$ (instead of as functions), then each $t$ is specified. Thus, $\cos t = -\sin t \cdot (-\frac{\cos t}{\sin t})$, and so they are linearly dependent. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @BrianMoehring But after a second thought, what if I am considering them as functions. $\begin{pmatrix} -\sin x \\ \cos x \end{pmatrix}$ is still of rank $1$. But $-\sin x$ and $\cos x$ are linearly independent, contradicts column rank being equal to row rank. What am I missing?

Comment: If you consider each entry as a function, we don't even have a $2\times 1$ matrix of values from $\mathbb{R}$ anymore.  Rather we need to consider the jacobian _itself_ as a function $(DF)(x) =  \left(\begin{array}{} -\sin x \\ \cos x\end{array}\right)$.  For each $x$ (or $t$, originally) value, we have a particular $2\times 1$ function with entries in $\mathbb{R}$, so for each $x$-value, we can compose to find the corresponding rank $\operatorname{rank} (DF)(x)$.  In your case, the rank of the jacobian is a constant function giving $1$ at every $x$-value, but this is not always the case.

Comment: correction: [...] we have a particular $2 \times 1$ **matrix** with entries in $\mathbb{R}$, so [...]

Comment: @BrianMoehring Thank you so much!